# Why is Collection.bulkwrite() writes only one document to the mongodb database

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have built this grid using ag-grid, and I am trying to bulkwrite its data in my mongodb database by clicking on the saveInformation button.
[image]

> app.component.ts

```
saveInformation() {
    console.log('actionPlanPartiesrowData: ', this.actionPlanPartiesrowData);
    this.saveInformationService
    .saveActionPlanInformation(this.actionPlanPartiesrowData)
    .subscribe((response) => {
          console.log('INSIDE ACTION PLAN COMPONENT INSIDE SUBSCRIBE saveInformation');
          console.log('response: ', response);
    });
}
```

> save-information.service.ts

```
  saveActionPlanInformation(actionPlanPartiesrowData
  ) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/fillActionPlan2`, actionPlanPartiesrowData, {
      responseType: "text"
    });
  }
```

In the backend:

> server.js

```
router.route('/fillActionPlan2').post((req, res) => {
    console.log('REQ.body of action plan is ', req.body);
    res.json('Action Plan data has been received on the server side')
    actionPlanRow.bulkWrite([{
        insertOne: {
            document: req.body[0]
        },
        insertOne: {
            document: req.body[1]
        },
        insertOne: {
            document: req.body[2]
        }
    }]).then(rest => {

        res.json(res.insertedCount, res.modifiedCount, res.deletedCount)
        console.log(rest.insertedCount, rest.modifiedCount, rest.deletedCount);
    });
})
```

Here's the data received in the backend: req.body:

> Req.body:

```
REQ.body of action plan is  [ { project: 'row1 data',
    id: 'row1 data',
    riskId: 'row1 data',
    iso27001: 'row1 data',
    priority: 'row1 data',
    projectOwner: 'row1 data',
    estimatedCost: 'row1 data' },
  { project: 'row 2 data',
    id: 'row 2 data',
    riskId: 'row 2 data',
    iso27001: 'row 2 data',
    priority: 'row 2 data',
    projectOwner: 'row 2 data',
    estimatedCost: 'row 2 data' },
  { id: 'row 3 data',
    project: 'row 3 data',
    riskId: 'row 3 data',
    priority: 'row 3 data',
    iso27001: 'row 3 data',
    projectOwner: 'row 3 data',
    estimatedCost: 'row 3 data*' },
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {} ]
```

After running:

> db.actionplanrows.find()

I always find only the last row inserted:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d1899417fe11c05ecd9e7eb"), "id" : "row 3 data", "project" : "row 3 data", "riskId" : "row 3 data", "priority" : "row 3 data", "iso27001" : "row 3 data", "projectOwner" : "row 3 data", "estimatedCost" : "row 3 data*" }
```

I don't understand why aren't the first and second row insert. Why is it that only the last insertOne() is executed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why bulkwrite inserts only the last document.
I solved the issue using insertMany instead of bulkwrite in this manner:

```
actionPlanRow.insertMany([req.body[0], req.body[1], req.body[2], req.body[3], req.body[4]], {
    multi: true
}
```

Hope this helps someone :))